# retrieving Polymorphic association correct model and id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I am new to polymorphic associations and am a bit lost at the moment.

I am trying to add a functionality to my website where users can ask quotes to different types of professionnals. Each professionnal own a specific type of quote such as :

model `photographer` own `photographerquotes`

I did this because each type of quotes is very dependable to the professional model it belongs to, and database model is specific for each.

Though one thing is constant with those quotes models : they can be commented either by the `user` or the `professionnal`

I have then made the different `quotes` models ***commentable*** but I am a bit lost when I need to create the commentable variable inside the comments controller #create action.

this tutorial says we can make modules https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations (at 15:00)

And the railscast here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOFAcbxdWjY grabs the correct quote model directly from the address bar with his following trick :

```
def load_commentable
   klass = [Article, Photo, Event].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
   @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
end
```

actually both seem counterintuitive to me as I am no Ruby expert, nor even Rails expert yet.

Is one of the two solutions a desired solution ? Are there some more possibilities in 2017 developping under rails 5 ?

EDIT

Actually there would be a third possibility :

it is to pass the `quote` model type and id inside the form as hidden fields. But it the gorails tutorial the person says that anybody can pass these data for us and this is not really safe ...

I am no HTPP expert but I thought the CREATE method couldnt be replicated inside the address bar. I thought only the GET method was 'public'...